# Iterating through array using jquery returns only last object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery and i think this is just a basic problem.    `

```
<input type="text" name="text1" value=""></input>
<input type="text" name="text2" value=""></input>
<input type="text" name="text3" value=""></input>
<input type="text" name="text4" value=""></input>
<input type="text" name="text5" value=""></input>       
<input type="submit" value="submit"></input>
<pre id="result">
</pre>
</form>`
```

This is my html form and i am using following jquery function to produce json object

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function()
{
var o = {};
var d={};
var a = this.serializeArray();
$.each(a, function(i,n) {
o['name'] = n['name'];
o['content'] =(n['value']);
});
return o; 
};
```

`$(function() {
     $('form').submit(function() {
     $('#result').text(JSON.stringify($('form').serializeObject()));
     return false;
     });

});`

on runnig the above html i am getting the output  `{"name":"text5","content":"sdsd"}`

just the final text field. i know am wrong somewhere . can someone help me to fix it. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are overwriting object's properties and the last values win, you can use an array and it's `push` method.

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
    var o = [];
    var a = this.serializeArray();
    $.each(a, function (i, n) {
        o.push({
            name: n['name'],
            content: n['value']  
        })
    });
    return o;
};
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kxM3e/

Using jQuery `map` method:

```
$.fn.serializeObject = function () {
    return this.find('input, textarea, select').map(function(){
        return { name: this.name, content: this.value };
    }).get();
};
```